# How to disable frequency scaling? Intel_pstate

Tags: scaling, cpufreq

Heyo,

I'm trying to disable the frequency scaling of one of my CPU and set the frequency to the maximum

I tried using `cpupower -c 1 frequency-set -g governor` and `-d 2600000` or with `cpufreq-set` but nothing works. I get this:

[image: cpufreq]

Comment: You have set the governor to "performance", so the frequency should already been set to the maximum. The real question is: why is your current frequency not at its maximum?

Comment: yes that's what I'm wondering :/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pstate-frequency](https://github.com/pyamsoft/pstate-frequency) to control the Intel P-state driver:

```
sudo pstate-frequency -S -n <integer percentage>
```

This sets the minimum frequency to whatever you choose.

Comment: weird thing is that you can only set for one CPU. Also it doesnt' change anything. CPU still running at 1.20GHz when I want it to run at 2.60Ghz

Comment: The only thing I can think of is thermal throttling, or the CPU going over its TDP. What CPU are you using? Are the temperatures okay?